# python extract xml element value to csv

Tags: python, xml

I'm a new to python so please bear with me as I try to explain what I am trying to do

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<playlist>
    <list>
        <txdate>2015-10-30</txdate>
        <channel>cake</channel>
        <name>Play List</name>
    </list>
    <eventlist>
        <event type="MEDIA">
            <title>title1</title>
            <starttype>FIX</starttype>
            <mediaid>a</mediaid>
            <onairtime>2015-10-30T13:30:00:00</onairtime>
            <som>00:00:40:03</som>
            <duration>01:15:47:15</duration>
            <reconcilekey>123</reconcilekey>
            <category>PROGRAM</category>
            <subtitles>
                <cap>CLOSED</cap>
                <file>a</file>
                <lang>ENG</lang>
                <lang>GER</lang>
            </subtitles>
        </event>
        <event type="MEDIA">
            <title>THREE DAYS AND A CHILD</title>
            <mediaid>b</mediaid>
            <onairtime>2015-10-30T14:45:47:15</onairtime>
            <som>00:00:00:00</som>
            <duration>01:19:41:07</duration>
            <reconcilekey>321</reconcilekey>
            <category>PROGRAM</category>
            <subtitles>
                <cap>CLOSED</cap>
                <file>b</file>
                <lang>ENG</lang>
                <lang>GER</lang>
            </subtitles>
        </event>
    </eventlist>
</playlist>
```

I would like to print all the mediaid values to a file
this is my code so far

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
wfile = 'new.csv'
for child in root: 
    child.find( "media type" )
    for x in child.iter("mediaid"):
        file = open(wfile, 'a')
        file.write(str(x))
    file.close
```

I tried this with a few other nonstandard libraries but I didn't have much success

Comment: So what are you expecting as output in your file? For the above example xml?

Comment: "a" on the first line "b" on the second line

Comment: So you simply want all the `mediad` values in the file? Without any condition, right?

Comment: yes just the `mediaid` from each `<event type="MEDIA">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement (as mentioned in the comments) -

> just the mediaid from each `<event type="MEDIA">`

You should use `findall()` method of ElementTree to get all the `event` elements with `type="MEDIA"` , and then get the child `mediaid` element from it. Example -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
with open('new.csv','w') as outfile:
    for elem in root.findall('.//event[@type="MEDIA"]'):
            mediaidelem = elem.find('./mediaid')
            if mediaidelem is not None:
                    outfile.write("{}\n".format(mediaidelem.text))
```